# Powershell and German umlauts

Tags: windows, powershell

I have written a script for my MySQL database with the Powershell ISE, which creates a backup for me with the help of the MySQL dump tool. 
When I run the script in the PowerShell ISE, everything works. If I execute the same script now in the normal PowerShell, he does not show me the German umlauts correctly.

Here is my script:

```
# delete everything older than 30 days
foreach ($ordner in (ls D:\Backup -Depth 0)) 
{
    if ($ordner.LastWriteTime.Date -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-30).Date)
    {
        rm -Recurse ("D:\Backup\"+ $ordner.Name)
    }
}


mkdir ("D:\Backup\" + (Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd") + "\Datenbank")

C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -uroot --default-character-set=latin1 --opt MY_DATABASE > ("D:\Backup\"+(Get-Date -Format "yyyy_MM_dd") + "\Datenbank\backup.sql")
```

However, I need the normal PowerShell for the automated execution and the script.

How can I fix the problem that the German umlauts are displayed in the normal PowerShell correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The **Windows PowerShell ISE** differs from regular (`conhost.exe`) PowerShell console windows in that it interprets the output from *external programs* (such as `mysqldump.exe`) as encoded based on the active **ANSI code page** (e.g., [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) on US-English systems) - which is what `--default-character-set=latin1` in your command requests.

- Note: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell [Core] 6+. The actively developed editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience, across platforms, is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

By contrast, **regular PowerShell console windows** default to the active **OEM code page** (e.g., [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) on US-English systems).

It is the encoding reported by **`[console]::OutputEncoding`** that **determines how PowerShell interprets the output from external programs** (though for mere *display* output that may not matter).

Therefore, you have two options:

- Adjust the `--default-character-set` option to match the code page reported by `[console]::OutputEncoding` - assuming MYSQL supports it ([this documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=1349) suggests that the US-English OEM code page 437 is *not* supported, for instance).
- Adjust `[console]::OutputEncoding` to (temporarily) match the specified `--default-character-set` option:

  - `[console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding(1252)`

In general, it is `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.ANSICodePage` / `(Get-Culture).TextInfo.OEMCodePage` that reports the a given system's active ANSI / OEM code page number.